# Installation of @mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

Tags: react-native, installation, background

I am building a react native app and I have to get user geolocation in background. I have this error when I run `npm run android` after I installed this library
https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\emanu\App\DetectApp - backup\DetectApp\node_modules\@mauron85\react-native-background-geolocation\android\common\VERSIONS.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

To install it I ran `yarn add @mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation` and `node ./node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/scripts/postlink.js` as described in the automatic setup

I also use react-native-maps so I add `googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.6.0"` in the ext of `android/build.gradle`

Why I have the error? Someone can help me please?

Very thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this before.
You need to do the manual setup

In android/settings.gradle

```
...
include ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'
project(':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common')
include ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation'
project(':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/lib')
...
```

In android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation')
    ...
}


You may see the full documentation here
https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation
```

Comment: Project with path ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation' could not be found in project ':app'.